# Clear cookies while logging out

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, cookies, vb.net-2010

i have a keep me logged in check box so i'm using cookies to implement it, but my problem is that i have 2 links to log out and when i click on each one i'm not being redirected to the log in page because on the load of the log in page i'm testing if the cookie is full and it's always full.. because when logging out i'm not able to clear the cookie...  i tried calling a function from back end to clear the cookie but it did not fire so can you help me please?

```
   Protected Sub btn_login_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_login.Click
    If Session("valid") Then
        If (loginkeeping.Checked = True) Then
            Dim mycookie As New HttpCookie("LoginDetail")
            Dim username As TextBox = Page.FindControl("username_txtt")
            Dim password As TextBox = Page.FindControl("passwordsignup")
            mycookie.Values("Username") = username.Text.Trim()
            mycookie.Values("Password") = password.Text.Trim()
            'mycookie.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)

            Response.Cookies.Add(mycookie)
        End If
        Response.Redirect("Insert_Content.aspx")
    End If
End Sub


    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not (Response.Cookies("LoginDetail") Is Nothing) Then
        Response.Redirect("Insert_Content.aspx")
    End If
End Sub
```

asp.net:

```
<ul id="nav" class="fl">
            <li class="v-sep">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="logUser" runat="server" class="round button dark menu-user image-left"></asp:HyperLink>
                <ul>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="Myprofile" NavigateUrl="~/Profile.aspx" runat="server">My Profile</asp:HyperLink>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="changePAss" NavigateUrl="~/Change_Password.aspx" runat="server">Change Password</asp:HyperLink></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="logout" NavigateUrl="~/LOGIN.aspx" runat="server" onClick="logoutt">Log out</asp:HyperLink></li>
                </ul> 
            </li>
            <li><a href="LOGIN.aspx" runat="server" class="round button dark menu-logoff image-left" onClick="logoutt">Log out</a></li>
        </ul> <!-- end nav -->


 Public Sub logoutt()
    Dim CookieName As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("username")
    CookieName.Expires.AddMilliseconds(1)
    CookieName.Value = Nothing
    Response.Cookies.Add(CookieName)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky thing about Cookies is even if you clear cookies they still Persist. So, the only thing we can do to remove cookie information is by expiring them.

Calling the Remove method of the Cookies collection removes the cookie from the collection on the server side, so the cookie will not be sent to the client. However, the method does not remove the cookie from the client if it already exists there.

```
You are misssing on following syntax:

Protected Sub btn_logout_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles
```

You need to provide arguments to the event handler..

Use the following code to clear cookies:

```
If (Not Request.Cookies("username") Is Nothing) Then
    Dim myCookie As HttpCookie
    myCookie = New HttpCookie("username")
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1D)
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie)
End If
```

Hope this helps..

**Create a new cookie with the same name and then expire it by setting expiry time to Past**

Comment: okey ... but if you check my asp code i'm not being able to clear my cookie when click on log out

Comment: You have create a cookie with the same name but should not assign it with old cookie as you are doing currently..remove that line

Comment: you are not getting my point..the clear of the cookie code is written in vb and my problem is that the event is not firing in vb when logging out...

Comment: my logout are a hyperlink and an a tag so i don't have an event on click !! so that's my problem !

Comment: okey i did but now i'm getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object